# How to call JTable.getColumn in Kotlin

Tags: swing, kotlin

How can I call `JTable.getColumn(x)` in Kotlin? The obvious code:

```
table.getColumn(0)
```

Results in this Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Identifier not found
```

Comment: Try `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0)`

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy - Aha, worked a treat! Thank-you :)

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy please make your comment an answer and paj28 please mark it as your answer